# Command Prompt - Batch File - BAT File

Tags: batch-file, encryption, cmd, command-prompt

I'd like to write a batch file so that all files in the given folder will be decrypted i.e FOR EACH file in a specified directory run the command I wrote below, using the current file name both for input and for output filename.

```
gpg --passphrase "MYPASS52381" -d -o "E:\filename.txt.PGP" "E:\filename.txt"
```

[image]

Comment: copy the text and paste here. [Please don't upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably best in a for loop, from batchfile:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.PGP) do gpg --passphrase "MYPASS52381" -d -o "%%~fi" "%%~dpni"
```

from cmdline:

```
for %i in (*.PGP) do gpg --passphrase "MYPASS52381" -d -o "%~fi" "%~dpni"
```

Opening command prompt, (`cmd.exe`), run `for /?` where you will see the variable references:

You can now use the following optional syntax (Note, I have changed variables to lowercase, to reflect your scenario):

```
%~i         - expands %i removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fi        - expands %i to a fully qualified path name
%~di        - expands %i to a drive letter only
%~pi        - expands %i to a path only
%~ni        - expands %i to a file name only
%~xi        - expands %i to a file extension only
%~si        - expanded path contains short names only
%~ai        - expands %i to file attributes of file
%~ti        - expands %i to date/time of file
%~zi        - expands %i to size of file
```

In other words in this case, as example, `%%~dpni` expands to Drive, Path and Name of `%%i` but excludes the file extension.

Comment: what does ~f & ~dpn mean?. Where can I get much more information or material to write queries like this.

Comment: Updated answer.